# Dynamicly centre align elements with css

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to dynamically centre two objects using only css ? By dynamically centre i mean if the size of one of the objects changes the css wouldn't have the change.

At the moment to achieve this non dynamically im using the css below, is there a way to do this without knowing the height dimensions of the child element before hand and thus not being able to set the `top:` and `left:` correctly ?

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
    <img src="myimageurl" width="100" height="100">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
}

.box img {
    margin-top: 50%;
    margin-left: 50%;
    position:relative;

/* These are the values id like to dynamically set */   

    top: -50px; /* being half of the image height */
    left: -50px; /* being half of the image width */
}
```

---

**Ive made a js fiddle of the issue here : http://jsfiddle.net/gnygxbxe/**

Comment: text-align:center; ?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to calculate any percentage position. Use pseudo element to centering it. You just need to make sure all element inside has properties `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle`.

Remember, elements inside box should be in 1 line. So if you wanted to put many of text, simply wrap the text as `span` or anything inside `.box` element.

For reference, read this : https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

See this snippet. IE8+ Supported.

```css
.box {
  margin: 20px;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border: #f0f0f0 solid 1px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
 
.box:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: -0.15em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.box > * {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="height: 300px;">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: table-cell`, `vertical-align` for vertical centering and `text-align` for horizontal centering.

```
.img {    
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gnygxbxe/1/

Answer (score 1):

```css
.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
}

.box img {   
    position:relative;  top: 50%; left: 50%; 
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <img src="http://www.reviversoft.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Spinning-Beach-Ball1.png" width="100" height="100">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you support 'evergreen' browsers, use css 'translate', see below:

```
.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
}

.box img {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gnygxbxe/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this also

```
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background:red;
  position:relative; 
}

.box img { 
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0; 
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}

.box img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.centered {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <span class="centered"></span>
    <img src="http://www.reviversoft.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Spinning-Beach-Ball1.png" width="100" height="100">
</div>
```